# Have a problem for using the {{restaurant.rest_id}} in the handlebars

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, express-handlebars

Here is the code as following. I run the server and try to test the edit-function. It showed the errormessage 'Cannot PUT /admin/restaurants/' when I finished edit and clicked the submit button.

I saw the URL didn't show {{restaurant.rest_id}} and check the route if the path is the same or not.

However, I ckeck everywhere, even compare the word one by one, cant find where is the problem and the other features is work. (like the create-function is work)

I try to use {{restaurant.id}} and modifiy the other codes and it can work after clikcing the submit button.

So, what the problem in these code? or it is just the expression rule for handlebars? I read the manual and didn't find the rule for underline.

(Maybe I type the wrong of keyword for searching this problem)

> creat-restaurant.hbs

```
<form action="/admin/restaurants" method="POST">
  <div class="mb-4 text-center">
    <h1 class="h3 font-weight-normal mb-3">Create Restaurant</h1>
  </div>

  {{> admin-restaurant-form}}
</form>
```

> edit-reataurant.hbs

```
<form action="/admin/restaurants/{{restaurant.rest_id}}?_method=PUT" method="POST">
  <div class="mb-4 text-center">
    <h1 class="h3 font-weight-normal mb-3">Edit Restaurant</h1>
  </div>
  {{> admin-restaurant-form}}
</form>
```

> admin-restaurant-form.hbs

```
<div class="form-row mb-3">
  <label class="form-label" for="name">Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" value="{{restaurant.name}}"
    required>
</div>
<div class="form-row mb-3">
  <label class="form-label" for="tel">Tel</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Enter tel" value="{{restaurant.tel}}">
</div>
<div class="form-row mb-3">
  <label class="form-label" for="address">Address</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Enter address"
    value="{{restaurant.address}}">
</div>
<div class="form-row mb-3">
  <label class="form-label" for="openingHours">Opening Hours</label>
  {{!-- note type="time" is not supported by Safari--}}
  <input class="form-control" type="time" name="openingHours" id="openingHours" placeholder="Enter opening hours"
    value="{{restaurant.openingHours}}">
</div>
<div class="form-row mb-3">
  <label class="form-label" for="description">Description</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" rows="3">{{restaurant.description}}</textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

> routes/modules/admin.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const adminController = require('../../controllers/admin-controller');

// Section all routes

router.get('/restaurants/create', adminController.createRestaurant);

router.get('/restaurants/:rest_id/edit', adminController.editRestaurant);

router.get('/restaurants/:rest_id', adminController.getRestaurant);

router.put('/restaurants/:rest_id', adminController.putRestaurant);

router.get('/restaurants', adminController.getRestaurants);

router.post('/restaurants', adminController.postRestaurant);

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/admin/restaurants');
});

module.exports = router;
```

> app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const { engine } = require('express-handlebars'); // the syntax is already changed by newest version
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('./config/passport');

const handlebarsHelpers = require('./helpers/handlebars-helpers'); 
const { getUser } = require('./helpers/auth-helpers');

const routes = require('./routes');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const SESSION_SECRET = 'secret';

app.engine('hbs', engine({ extname: '.hbs', helpers: handlebarsHelpers }));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

app.use(
  session({ secret: SESSION_SECRET, resave: false, saveUninitialized: false })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // active session function

app.use(flash());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.success_messages = req.flash('success_messages');
  res.locals.error_messages = req.flash('error_messages');
  res.locals.user = getUser(req);
  next();
});

app.use(routes);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.info(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

> controllers/admin-controller.js

```
const { Restaurant } = require('../models');
const { localFileHandler } = require('../helpers/file-helpers');

const adminController = {
  // the object
  getRestaurants: (req, res, next) => {
    Restaurant.findAll({ raw: true })
      .then(restaurants => {
        res.render('admin/restaurants', { restaurants });
      })
      .catch(err => next(err));
  },
  createRestaurant: (req, res) => {
    return res.render('admin/create-restaurant');
  },
  postRestaurant: (req, res, next) => {
    const { name, tel, address, openingHours, description } = req.body;
    if (!name) throw new Error('Restaurant name is required');

    const file = req.file;
 
    localFileHandler(file)
      .then(filePath => {
        return Restaurant.create({
          name,
          tel,
          address,
          openingHours,
          description,
          image: filePath || null
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        req.flash('success_messages', 'Restaurant was created successfully');
        res.redirect('/admin/restaurants');
      })
      .catch(err => next(err));
  },
  getRestaurant: (req, res, next) => {
    Restaurant.findByPk(req.params.rest_id, { raw: true })
      .then(restaurant => {
        if (!restaurant) throw new Error("Restaurant didn't exist");

        res.render('admin/restaurant', { restaurant });
      })
      .catch(err => next(err));
  },
  editRestaurant: (req, res, next) => {
    Restaurant.findByPk(req.params.rest_id, { raw: true })
      .then(restaurant => {
        if (!restaurant) throw new Error("Restaurant didn't exist");

        res.render('admin/edit-restaurant', { restaurant });
      })
      .catch(err => next(err));
  },
  putRestaurant: (req, res, next) => {
    const { name, tel, address, openingHours, description } = req.body;
    if (!name) throw new Error('Restaurant name is required');

    const { file } = req;

    Promise.all([
      Restaurant.findByPk(req.params.rest_id),
      localFileHandler(file)
    ])
      .then(([restaurant, filePath]) => {
        if (!restaurant) throw new Error("Restaurant didn't exist");

        return restaurant.update({
          name,
          tel,
          address,
          openingHours,
          description,
          image: filePath || restaurant.image
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        req.flash('success_messages', 'Restaurant was updated successfully');
        res.redirect('/admin/restaurants');
      })
      .catch(err => next(err));
  },
  deleteRestaurant: (req, res, next) => {
    return Restaurant.findByPk(req.params.rest_id)
      .then(restaurant => {
        if (!restaurant) throw new Error("Restaurant didn't exist !!");

        return restaurant.destroy();
      })
      .then(() => res.redirect('/admin/restaurants'))
      .catch(err => next(err));
  }
};

module.exports = adminController;
```

Already check all the path and check the word one by one. Hope can find the problem and how should I notice.

Note:
Here is the result from `console.log(restaurant)` before `res.render('admin/edit-restaurant', { restaurant }`.
And the info is fake.

```
{
  id: 158,
  name: 'Lonnie Rath',
  tel: '1-380-799-1151 x9618',
  address: '1901 Dandre Light',
  openingHours: '8:00',
  description: 'Sed veniam dolore non. In maxime eius dicta necessitatibus nobis repellat autem fuga nemo. Reprehenderit repellendus ad non ratione quisquam esse occaecati. Sed minima similique neque aspernatur in perferendis at eum dolore. Quia sit vel autem sunt.',
  image: 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240/restaurant,food/?random=86.22619138396297',
  createdAt: 2023-01-31T04:14:46.000Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-01-31T04:14:46.000Z
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that your `restaurant` object has a `rest_id` property?

Comment: Hi @76484, I print the result and it show that `rest_id`when I `console.log(req.params)`. However, I just only saw the id when I used `consol.log(restaurant)`.

And I am sorry that I forgot to post the important code of the controller and I already added it. Maybe the problem is in the controller.

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(restaurant)` before the `res.render('admin/edit-restaurant', { restaurant });` line in your `editRestaurant` handler?

Comment: I paste the `console.log(restaurant)` and it shows in the last code block.

Comment: So there is no `rest_id` property on `restaurant`. It's not clear why you thought there should be one. You should just use `restaurant.id` in your form `action` attribute

Comment: Hi @Phil, thanks for your suggestion. I just want to try if it can change the `id` name or not because I want it can be  identified easily where it come from  when I write the code.

Comment: You can name your request parameter anything you want (ie `/restaurants/:rest_id` / `req.params.rest_id`). The properties on your models are fixed though. You cannot use properties that don't exist